How do i contain child Div inside Parent Div with self growing vertically?
I have the below Code to show Customer Feedback and the content is overflowing always and not auto sizing within. Can someone please help. I wanted the keep the Testimonial Div with fixed height and width and show scroll bar vertically for Content div if it grows
<drag-scroll #nav>
  <div class="testimony-container">
    <div
      drag-scroll-item
      class="testimony"
      *ngFor="let t of testimonialList; let i = index"
    >
      <mat-icon>format_quote</mat-icon>
      <div class="title">{{ t.title }}</div>
      <div class="content" [title]="t.content">{{ t.content }}</div>
      <div class="price">{{ t.customerName }}</div>
      <div class="price">{{ t.date }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</drag-scroll>

CSS
drag-scroll {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.testimony-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.testimony {
  width: 275px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(196, 196, 196);
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  width: 275px;
  height: 60px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

Current behavior


Perhaps creating a snippit that displays the some actual text in your code would assist.

Unfortunately your issue wasn't reproduced on my side, however you might try a little update for the styles of element .content:
.content {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* ...rest */
}

Also, would be nice if you could to provide a screen from dev-inspector. It's interesting are there any additional styles playing role...

the main problem is i am using ngx-drag-scroll and this tag is causing the problem <drag-scroll #nav>, when i replace it with DIV, it works
